# In ArcMap 10.3 when making a feature record I am getting different values than I have in the domain, why?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, domains

I have a feature class in a GDB of road survey points, it has a domain assigned to the field of "Type".  When I look at the domain values in the GDB properties I see the entry code="Culvert - Proposed" and it's description is "Culvert - Proposed".

When I start editing on that feature class and go to create a feature I see in the create features window the icon for that layer with the text "Culvert - Proposed".  I select that and create a point feature but when I look at the attribute values for the new feature I see the "Type" attribute as "CulvertProp".

I can't seem to find where this other value comes from as I would expect it would be "Culvert - Proposed" as I see in the domain.

Any leads where it could be coming from?

I inherited the GDB so not sure how that was set up.

Answer (score 1):

The value seems to come from a default value assigned in a Subtype created on the feature class.   However the tricky bit comes from there being no actual subtype assigned to the feature class, but a default value for a subtype still exists despite the feature class having no long integer fields to create a sybtype off of.

The fix is:

-create a temporary field in the feature class to get fixed, make it long integer

-close the feature class properties window and reopen to force the SubTypes tab to refresh ("apply" does not work for this).

-Then reopen the feature class properties, go into the Subtypes tab and in "Subtype Field:" select your temporary field in the drop down menu.  A new subtype will be crested.

-Now switch the same dropdown menu back to "" and you will get a warning that all subtypes will be removed.  Accept this and your problematic default value will be removed.

-Now you can go back to the Fields tab and delete your temporary long integer field.